# CSS not updating on Node.js?

Tags: html, node.js, wordpress, npm, gulp

**Trying to get the css to update on the browser using browser sync via Gulp on Node.js... What am I doing wrong?**

This is the Gulp.js file

```
    var themename = 'playtest haha 1';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    // Prepare and optimize code etc
    autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    image = require('gulp-image'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),

    // Only work with new or updated files
    newer = require('gulp-newer'),

    // Name of working theme folder
    root = '../' + themename + '/',
    scss = root + 'sass/',
    js = root + 'js/',
    img = root + 'images/',
    languages = root + 'languages/';


// CSS via Sass and Autoprefixer
gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src(scss + '{style.scss,rtl.scss}')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({
        outputStyle: 'expanded', 
        indentType: 'tab',
        indentWidth: '1'
    }).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(postcss([
        autoprefixer('last 2 versions', '> 1%')
    ]))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write(scss + 'maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(root));
});

// Optimize images through gulp-image
gulp.task('images', function() {
    return gulp.src(img + 'RAW/**/*.{jpg,JPG,png}')
    .pipe(newer(img))
    .pipe(image())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(img));
});

// JavaScript
gulp.task('javascript', function() {
    return gulp.src([js + '*.js'])
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(js));
});


// Watch everything
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    browserSync.init({ 
        open: 'external',
        proxy: 'http://localhost/wordpress', /* add your local host so the task can since the browser thing a bob*/
        port: 8080
    });
    gulp.watch([root + '**/*.css', root + '**/*.scss' ], ['css']);
    gulp.watch(js + '**/*.js', ['javascript']);
    gulp.watch(img + 'RAW/**/*.{jpg,JPG,png}', ['images']);
    gulp.watch(root + '**/*').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});


// Default task (runs at initiation: gulp --verbose)
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

**I have using the "local server"** link to view the website project on browser and the `proxying :http://localhost` (do I add the /wordpress path?)

Node.js terminal screen: https://imgur.com/a/9lUNi

**Not sure why the css is not updating, the browser sync sign is shown on the browsers and seem to be in sync (tested with multiple browsers), the css is not updating?!**

Answer (score 0):

You need to pipe to browserSync at the end of your 'css' task ala:

```
// CSS via Sass and Autoprefixer
gulp.task('css', function() {
  return gulp.src(scss + '{style.scss,rtl.scss}')
   .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
   .pipe(sass({
      outputStyle: 'expanded', 
      indentType: 'tab',
      indentWidth: '1'
   }).on('error', sass.logError))
   .pipe(postcss([
    autoprefixer('last 2 versions', '> 1%')
   ]))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write(scss + 'maps'))     
  .pipe(gulp.dest(root))
  .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream:true }));
});
```

Your

```
gulp.watch(root + '**/*').on('change', browserSync.reload);
```

will probably run into lots of **race** **conditions** (as for instance running before the 'css' task finishes and running multiple times) and I would remove it and put the reload pipe at the end of your 'javascript' and 'images' tasks as well.

Comment: Okay copied the exact code, hasn't worked. New to this so I don't know what I am doing... is there a way to make this work without sass css perhaps it would be easier. Also in the: gulp.task('css', function()... should I change the name 'css' to my stylesheet or it doesn't matter? thanks1

Comment: Are you getting any modified css output at all when you modify a scss or css file?  Just look at the new css file - does it have your changes?  And is that css file the one you link to in your html?  Leave it as gulp.task('css'...  That is the name you link to in your watch css/scss call.

Comment: Okay, I've changed my question to give better context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46627119/using-gulp-js-with-css-not-sass-possible

Comment: I see your other question .Your code is generally good except for my comments about the race conditions above.  So that often means your src's aren't correct.  You use return gulp.src(scss + '{style.scss,rtl.scss}') :  is the css you are editing located within that src?  If not, you should put its relative path (from the gulpfile.js into the gulp.src('relativePathtoMyCSS')

Comment: So  i should put my relative css path in there? The problem is this... The gulp.js file is located in gulp-dev folder in ../wordpress/wp-content/themes/gulp-dev and the css file is in ./wordpress/wp-content/themes/newT/style.css

Comment: So the relative path would be: ../newT/stye.css ?

Comment: Also the other question is related to just css since i think sass is complicating it for me!

Comment: If I understand you right, that relative path looks right. Or if there is more than  one css file in there: "../newt/*.css"

Answer (score 0):

I just had a very frustrating couple of days battling css that refused to update and finally solved it by disabling caching in the Network tab of Chrome Developer Tools. Worked like a charm. I know this is an old question, but thought I'd add the suggestion here for people who find themselves in the same position in the future.